# Change select option based on attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to change a `select option` on `click` but I don't want to use the `option value`. My code works if I give my button a `value='3'` but what I want is to select the one with `data-price="0"` which in my case is the one with `value='3'`.

JS :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#sample-addtocart-button').click(function(){
        jQuery('.product-custom-option').val(jQuery(this).attr('value'));
    });
});
```

Html :

```
<button value="0" id="sample-addtocart-button" type="button">Free</button>

<select class="product-custom-option">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option data-price="10" value="1">£10.00</option>
    <option data-price="20" value="2">£20.00</option>
    <option data-price="0" value="3">FREE</option>
</select>
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [attribute equals selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to get the option and then select option by setting `selected` property using **[`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/)** method.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#sample-addtocart-button').click(function() {
    jQuery('.product-custom-option option[data-price="' + jQuery(this).attr('value') + '"]').prop('selected', true);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button value="0" id="sample-addtocart-button" type="button">Free</button>

<select class="product-custom-option">
  <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
  <option data-price="10" value="1">£10.00</option>
  <option data-price="20" value="2">£20.00</option>
  <option data-price="0" value="3">FREE</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can select elements by attribute, and then set the `selected` property on the element.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#sample-addtocart-button').click(function(){
        jQuery('.product-custom-option [data-price=' + this.value + ']').prop("selected", true);
    });
});
```

This selects the element with a `data-price` attribute equal to the value of `this.value`, which is a descendant of `.product-custom-option`, and sets its `selected` property to `true`.

---

Without jQuery, it could look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.querySelector('#sample-addtocart-button').addEventListener("click", function(){
    document.querySelector('.product-custom-option [data-price=' + this.value + ']').selected = true;
  });
});
```

---

And a handful of helper methods always helps with the verbosity:

```
function listen(el, typ, fn, cap) {
  el && el.addEventListener(typ, fn, cap)
}
function query(el, sel) {
  if (typeof el === "string") {
    sel = el;
    el = document;
  }
  return el.querySelector(sel)
}
```

```
listen(document, "DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  listen(query('#sample-addtocart-button'), "click", function(){
    query('.product-custom-option [data-price=' + this.value + ']').selected = true;
  });
});
```

Comment: Cheers mate, much appreciated!

Comment: My pleasure. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery('#sample-addtocart-button').click(function(){
        var val= jQuery(this).attr('value');
        jQuery('.product-custom-option option[data-price='+val+']').prop('selected', true); // it will find the select option with certain data-price and make it selected
});
```